# How to find out which subtotal make up a sum?

Tags: algorithm, sum, subtotal

I need to find numbers in a list, which make up a specific total:

```
Sum: 500

Subtotals: 10 490 20 5 5

In the end I need: {10 490, 490 5 5}
```

How do you call this type of problem? Are there algorithms to solve it efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Looks like a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem.

Comment: I am currently going through this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: Can there be negative numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and it is an NP-complete problem, i.e. there is no efficient algorithm known for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is **not** a knapsack problem.
2. In the worst case, with N subtotals, there can be O(2^N) solutions, so any algorithm in worst-case will be no better than this (thus, the problem doesn't belong to NP class at all).

Let's assume there are no non-positive elements in the Subtotals array and any element is no greater than Sum. We can sort array of subtotals, then build array of tail sums, adding 0 to the end. In your example, it will look like:

```
Subtotals:   (490, 20, 10,  5, 5)  
PartialSums: (530, 40, 20, 10, 5, 0)
```

Now for any "remaining sum" S, position i, and "current list" L we have problem E(S, i, L):
E(0, i, L) = (print L).
E(S, i, L) | (PartialSums[i] < S) = (nothing).
E(S, i, L) = E(S, i+1, L), E(S-Subtotals[i], j, L||Subtotals[i]), where j is index of first element of Subtotals lesser than or equal to (S-Subtotals[i]) or i+1, whichever is greater.
Our problem is E(Sum, 0, {}).

Of course, there's a problem with duplicates (if there were another 490 number in your list, this algorithm would output 4 solutions). If that's not what you need, using array of pairs (value, multiplicity) may help.

**P.S.** You may also consider dynamic programming if size of the problem is small enough:

1. Start with set {0}. Create array of sets equal to array of subtotals in size.
2. For every subtotal create a new set from previous set by adding subtotal value. Remove all elements greater than Sum. Merge it with previous set (it will essentially be the set of all possible sums).
3. If in the final set doesn't have Sum, then there is no solution. Otherwise, you backtrack solution from Sum to 0, checking whether previous set contains [value] and [value-subtotal].
   Example:

   (10, 490, 20, 5, 5)

Sets:

```
(0)
(0, 10)
(0, 10, 490, 500)
(0, 10, 20, 30, 490, 500) (510, 520 - discarded)
(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 490, 495, 500)
(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 490, 495, 500)
```

From last set: [500-5] in previous set, [495-5] in previous set, [490-20] not in previous set ([490] is), [490-490] is 0, resulting answer {5, 5, 490}.

Comment: I fail to fundamentally understand what your solutions do, but I'm certain that the original problem is a Knapsack problem. For n elements in the original list, there are 2<sup>n</sup> subsets of those elements and you need to identify those whose sum is exactly a given integer. Finding ONE such a subset is already Knapsack-hard. The problem is not made easier by having to enumerate all of them.

Comment: First: knapsack problem requires two sets of numbers, weights and costs. Second: knapsack problem is about finding whether there exists a layout that fits in the knapsack and costs more than given N. Thus, hypothetical solution of the knapsack problem cannot be converted to solution of this problem easily, they are different problems. And third: knapsack problem is NP-complete, which means that it is "equivalent" to the SAT problem. Problem presented by Kiril is **not** NP, because in worst case it can't be solved in polynomial time (having output of non-polynomial size).

Comment: look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Direct_generalizations. The case where weight equals cost is listed there, with remark "If for each item the profits and weights are identical, we get the subset sum problem." Subset problem is also NP-complete. And yes, enumerating all solutions for any problem that can have exponentially many is not a problem in NP. When I wrote "it is a Knapsack problem" I was simplifying. I guess I should have written that "the decision version already is a Knapsack-like NP-complete problem often known as subset sum".

Comment: Well, there still are some differences. First, we don't want to get "as close as possible" to target sum, we want to hit it exactly. Second, there are (presumably) no negative numbers. Under these conditions, I don't see an obvious way to derive solution of another NP-complete problem from problem (find a single subset of partial sums).  Also, knapsack problem is NP-complete if and only if **size** of knapsack capacity is unbounded (say, it can be 60 or 100 or 500 bits long number). Otherwise, problem is not NP-complete and polynomial solution exists.